# how to concatate in vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

i have small issue with vue.

I want to concatate string with variable, but i have error:

```
Unexpected string concatenation  / prefer-template
```

I want to concatate

```
const key = 'x: ' + cmd.event.text
```

i was trying to use:

```
      const name = cmd.event.text
      const key = 'x: ${name}'
```

but then i have different error:

```
 error    'name' is assigned a value but never used     no-unused-vars
  error    Unexpected template string expression        no-template-curly-in-string
```

Can you help me, how to concatate in vue?

Comment: You want to use backticks, not single quotes

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=Unexpected+template+string+expression+site:stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use template literal.

```
const key = `x: ${name}`
```